# Load Webview in second Fragment when Button is clicked from First Fragment

Tags: eclipse, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-webview

I have two Fragments. First Fragment is named as Fragment1 and Second Fragment named as physics. First Fragment have Two Buttons. I would Like to show a local html page ( say A.html when Button1 is pressed and B.html when Button2 is Pressed ) in Second Fragment i.e in physics.java

My Fragment.java contains following code

```html
package com.nepalpolice.mnemonics;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;

/**
 * Created by Sagar on 2017/09/23.
 */

public class Fragment1 extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

        public Button button;


    public Fragment1() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.button2);


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), physics.class);

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                intent.putExtra("url", "file:///android_asset/B.html");
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            case R.id.button2:
                intent.putExtra("url", "file:///android_asset/A.html");
                startActivity(intent);
                break;

            default:
                break;


        }
    }
}
```

and My SecondFragment contains following code

```html
package com.nepalpolice.mnemonics;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

/**
 * Created by Sagar on 2017/09/23.
 */

public class physics extends Fragment {

  WebView myWebView;
    public physics() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment2, container,  false);


        String url = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("url");
        myWebView=(WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl(url);

        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return false;
            }
        });
        return rootView;

    }
}
```

and main fragment_fragment1.xml contains

```html
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.nepalpolice.mnemonics.Fragment1">


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >



        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="button01"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="button02"
            android:onClick="onClick"/>




    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

and Secondfragment.xml has

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But my is Crashing with following Error.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button1'
```

I'm almost Done with my project. If it could be done...It would mean a lot for me.